# Getting value from Message Controller in Calling Controller in Skype Bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-skype-bot

I'm working on a Skype bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework. I have a MessageController and CallingController. I'm trying to somehow link the information obtained from the MessageController with a function within the calling controller.

While a calling session will go on, User will be asked to type a alphanumeric value to chat. Calling session will wait for that value to be received. Once its received call session will process the value based on logic written.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: Is the call continuing or ending dependent on user's chat input or is there some other expected outcome? Any other information, including code, you can provide would be useful.